# Vagrant sharing local WordPress installation

Tags: wordpress, apache, vagrant

So I have a WordPress site I created locally using a vagrant environment and I would like to test it on a mobile device using vagrants `vagrant share` feature. I do have vagrant share working for other projects however WordPress is presenting itself as a challenge.

What happens is I get the vagrant share url however WordPress or Apache is rewriting the url into the development URL. I'm suspecting this to be an apache fix. Am I right? Is there any documented solutions for sharing a local dev WordPress site using vagrant share?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to enable WordPress to handle multiple domains to a single instance.

I modified the `wp-config.php` file to include

`define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
 define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);`